# Resuming a large video uploading on Youtube

Tags: youtube

I am uploading a large Video to youtube.It is currently being uploaded.I want to stop it as the weather is quite bad in here and resume it whenever it is good to keep the router going on.Is it possible ? i have downloaded 45% uploaded.Thanks

Comment: Just out of interest, what does the weather have to do with your router?

Comment: The lightening strikes roasted my whole setup,i am not going to let that happen again in future @stib

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.You can. It is officially announced the Youtube has brought up the [**FEATURE**](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4525858?hl=en&ref_topic=2888603). If you had to abandon your upload for any reason, you have up to 24 hours to continue uploading where you left off.You can cancel the upload and whenever you want to download within the 24 hours time you can go to upload manager and select the same file and resume the upload.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply ! Cheers.I tested it just now with another short video,It works! Thank you !

Comment: Great! Glad it helped you out.Cheers!

Comment: I also recognized this! This is a real killer feature!

Answer (score 0):

It does not always work I have a 2.37gb video stuck at 77% and each time I try to upload it it creates a new upload.

I even disabled my network card to invoke loss of internet and it still does the same thing! Youtube is absolutely FULL of bugs I wish I? had never started my channel its a mess!!!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/20510)